# Find first value with datediff larger than 1 week from table and join with initial table

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, common-table-expression, datediff

I have two tables:

- `dbo.HistPrices` (Which has all Historic Prices for every PId and some non interesting metadata... etc. )

| PId (non-unique) | Price | Pricedate | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2022-11-03 |  |
| 2 | 3 | 2022-11-03 |  |
| 2 (more than 1 date per week) | 3.2 | 2022-11-02 |  |
| 1 | 6 | 2022-10-27 |  |
| 2 | 3.4 | 2022-10-27 |  |

- and `dbo.Stuff` (which is like a shopping cart of some sort where the given Price is the price in the current week for a specific item which is encapsulated in the Sid )

| SId (unique) | Price | Pricedate | desc | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 2022-11-10 |  |  |
| 2 | 2.9 | 2022-11-10 |  |  |
| 3 | 7 | 2022-11-10 |  |  |

The SId and PId have different names also the HistPrices table carries also information for items which are not related to the stuff Table.

What I want is a Table like this:

| SId | Price | Pricedate | desc | ... | last_week_Price | Last_week_PriceDAte | week_before Price | week before date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 2022-11-10 |  |  | 5 | 2022-11-03 | 6 | 2022-10-27 |
| 2 | 2.9 | 2022-11-10 |  |  | 3 | 2022-11-03 | 3.4 | 2022-10-27 |

So, I want to create two columns in the `dbo.Stuff` table which get last week's price and the price from the week before. I can not be sure that there is only one price from last week (see the 2022-11-02 Price for PId 2).

So, if there are more prices from last week, I just want to grab the first one which is at least a week old. Similar for the price from the week before. Only the first price which is at least 2 weeks older needs to be fetched.

Another must is, that the length of dbo.Stuff is not changed. So, if no price is found, None should be inserted.

I got a solution for an individual part with a CTE, but I don't know how to form the correct join/insert statement.

My CTE for an individual SId, which I set manually, looks like this:

```
DECLARE @get_Date VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SId int
DECLARE @week_offset int
SET @get_Date = 'teststring in date format' 
SET @SId = 12345
SET @week_offset  = -1;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                  PARTITION BY hp.PId
                  ORDER BY  hp.PriceDate DESC 
--- i also thoguth abut DATEDIFF(week, hp.Pricedate,CONVERT(DATETIME,@get_Date) )
              ) rn
    FROM   dbo.HistPrices hp
    WHERE (hp.Pricedate >= DATEADD(Week, @week_offset,CONVERT(DATETIME,@get_Date))
    AND hp.Pricedate < CONVERT(DATETIME,@get_Date) ) 
     AND hp.PId = @SId
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY PId
```

I'm struggling to join the two tables for all ids like this. So, I think I get the correct result when I choose an ID manually, but I can somehow not join the two tables with this information.

Edit: I added some actual dates as requested in the comment

Comment: Please show us your **actual** data, especially with actual *dates* - and the corresponding expected result. It is not that clear what you call *the price from last week* - and the concept of week itself is not consistent across the globle.

Comment: @GMB I added some actual dates. I hope this is clearer now. Thank you for taking the time to have a look at this.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this a variety of ways depending on the requirements, but the first option that comes to mind would be to simply use an [outer apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#using-apply). Other options would include using ranking functions like row_number or analytic functions like first_value/last_value, or standard joins and CTEs if the requirements allow for it.

A simple example using a CROSS APPLY operation would be as follows:

```
select  s.sid, s.price, s.pricedate,
        l.price as last_week_price,
        l.pricedate as last_week_pricedate
from    dbo.Stuff s
outer apply
        (
        select  top 1
                h.price, h.pricedate
        from    dbo.HistPrices h
        where   h.pid = s.sid
                -- Starting 1 week (i.e. 7 days) before the sid.pricedate...NOT on the week start of the week before
                and h.pricedate >= dateadd(week, -1, s.pricedate)
                -- If you'd rather start on the start of the week of the week before sid.pricedate, it'd be this
                -- and h.pricedate >= dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, s.pricedate) - 1, 0)
                and h.pricedate < dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, s.pricedate), 0)
        order by
                h.pricedate
        ) l;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But wouldn´t this solution squencially scan the table? It would be really appreciated, if you could show me how to solve this with a cte.

Comment: @NorrinRadd that would depend on your schema/indexing/usage and a variety of other factors, but if your question is more related to the use of APPLY and their viability for seeking/plan selection, they most certainly are. i.e. using an APPLY does not force/guarantee a table scan, it can/will be optimized in the plan.   If you leave no filter/where clause on the outer query (i.e. get all Stuff records), you'll always wind up with a scan naturally.